# Elasticsearch - repository_exception

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7, elasticsearch-snapshot

While restoring the index via snapshot, I am getting `repository_exception`.

> Error - Could not read repository data because the contents of the repository do not match its expected state. This is likely the result of either concurrently modifying the contents of the repository by a process other than this cluster or an issue with the repository's underlying storage. The repository has been disabled to prevent corrupting its contents. To re-enable it and continue using it please remove the repository from the cluster and add it again to make the cluster recover the known state of the repository from its physical contents."

I am facing this issue after upgrading the Elasticsearch from **v6.8x** to **v7.3**

To create the snapshot I am using the below command-

```
curl -X PUT "http://url:9200/_snapshot/test" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' {
    "type": "fs",
    "settings": {
        "location": "/mnt/stgintessnap/weekly_snap" 
    }
}
'
```

Comment: Hi @sumit, welcome to this community! Would you mind taking some time and sharing what you learned from this issue? If your problem was solved, you can answer your own question and mark it a s accepted solution. That way you can contribute back and others can benefit from it. Best regards!

Comment: This discussion may be helpful: [Restore from S3 repository_exception](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/restore-from-s3-repository-exception/268848)